# How to override SQLAdmin(SQLAlchemy Admin for FastAPI and Stallete) to show username on successful login into the admin dashboard

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, admin, fastapi

I've been a able to integrate SQLAdmin with FastAPI and also overridden the template. How do I serve the template to a route that can display the username when a user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best option though. What I did was update the request session with the user data in the AuthenticationBackEnd and using the SessionMiddlware.

```py
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key=SECRET_KEY, max_age=MAX_AGE)

class MohDeliveryAdmin(AuthenticationBackend):
    async def login(self, request: Request) -> bool:

        form = await request.form()
        username, password = form["username"], form["password"]

        user = session.query(User).filter(User.email == username).first()

        if not user:
            invalid_exception("Invalid username or password!")

        # Validate username/password credentials
        if not verify_password(password, user.password):
            invalid_exception("Invalid Credentials!")
        user_data = {
            "id": user.id,
            "username": user.username or None,
            "email": user.email,
            "phone_number": user.phone_number,
            "user_type": user.user_type,
            "company_name": user.company_name or None,
        }

        # And update session
        access_token = auth.create_access_token(data=user_data)
        request.session.update({"token": access_token, "user": user_data})
        return True
```